# Phone Storage Problems

Tags: htc

I am having an issue where I have no free space. I have deleted a few apps and removed cache from all and it gives me some free space. I then go to delete to a text message from microsoft and I cannot get to the menu to delete it and messages crash and I then have no free space again.

Anyone know how to fix this issue? Is the message causing the lack of space problem or is the lack of space causing the message app to crash?

Thanks
HenGreer

Answer (score 0):

You're probably having a problem using your device because of lack of internal space for running programs.  You can use a very low level, low resource on the Android to remove programs.  Install the [Android SDK package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and use it to uninstall some of your apps to regain internal memory.  You can even use it to back up the apps on your computer so that after you have your android working again you can choose which ones to put back.

A good GUI program for managing your apps and deleting files from your android is Airdroid.  However, you might not be able to install Airdrod until you've made space using the Android SDK package.

You can start out with these commands:
(You'll have to activate Debugging from the settings menu in the android to use this option)
This give a list of all the packages:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages
```

You can remove an app by running:

```
$ adb uninstall [apt-name]
```

You can use the "-k" option to retain your data/cache in case you will be reinstalling the app after you have gotten your android functioning.

You can us this command to see how much memory you have.  This will allow you to know when you have retrieve sufficient memory to operate normally.  It'll also allow you to identify better, if the memory is really your issue.

```
$ adb shell cat /proc/meminfo
```

You can look at [Is it possible to backup apk from an installed application?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75360/is-it-possible-to-backup-apk-from-an-installed-application) for more tips on using the adb command.