# Is it possibile to extract individual files from a .ab backup file?

Tags: backup, android-sdk, macos

If I run:

adb backup -apk -shared -all -f \Path\to\backup.ab

Can I then later extract the .ab file on OSX to view and edit individual files?

Comment: You already answered it by yourself. However, I must add this too http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75360/is-it-possible-to-backup-apk-from-an-installed-application/75436#75436

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this tool](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) might be able to do this. A search for 'android backup extractor' also returns a couple of alternatives